# Deleting files on btrfs through smb

Tags: btrfs, smb

I have set up a btrfs multidisk which I mount and have shared on the network through smb. Whenever someone deletes a file on the share in windows, it seems to be rather slow. Any ideas/options I need to set in smb or btrfs which could speed that up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Btrfs *is slow* with delete by design. The only option of speeding up process is by lazy deleting on samba's part. But I doubt this feature exists there (but maybe I'm wrong). To say the truth I doubt that lazy deleting files exists in Linux kernel at all.

You can change Samba's behavior from deleting to *moving* files into a directory ".trash". See [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64296/how-do-i-enable-trash-functionality-on-samba-shares). It works for me.

Comment: This is what I feared, maybe I could make something that when samba deletes a file, it really moves the file to some non-shared folder and then have a script delete all the files in there? I don't know if you can configure smb to behave like that

Comment: Good thought. And, yes, you can do it. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/64296/how-do-i-enable-trash-functionality-on-samba-shares.